# Selecting specific divs to set attributes with eventListener

Tags: javascript, css

I have this game done, Tic-Tac-Toe but I'm looking into how to put colours on winner squares or draw a line. The css of making the square or line is easy but I don't know how to go about selecting just the winning squares when my winningCombos look like this :

```
const winningCombos = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6]]
```

And the way the player's moves are inserted in an array to check the combos later. For example, maybe one player takes 5 moves to win but I just need to winning 3 squares.

```
xChoices = [0,1,3,6] // where 0,3,6 are winners and I want to draw a line on them or put a colour
```

the way I check the combos:

```
function checkForXWinner(){
        return winningCombos.some(combo =>{
            return combo.every(e =>{
                return xChoices.includes(e)
            })
        })
    }

    function checkForOWinner(){
        return winningCombos.some(combo =>{
            return combo.every(e =>{
                return oChoices.includes(e)
            })
        })
    }
```

here is the jsfiddle, cheers.

https://jsfiddle.net/6zbdgrmy/

Comment: Store the result of `combo.every` in a variable. Check it against being true. If it's true, the combo contains the fields you want to color. Finally, return the variable. (also, if you pass `xChoices` / `oChoices` as variable to the function, you don't need two of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to color those squares you could as well find the corresponding array in the mutidimensional array and color each square separately

Example:

```
const winningCombos = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
]

xChoices = [0, 1, 3, 6]

const winArrayIndex = winningCombos
  .map(arr => arr.every(y => xChoices.includes(y)))
  .findIndex(x => x)

for (let i = 0; i < winningCombos[winArrayIndex].length; i++) {
  console.log('color:', winningCombos[winArrayIndex][i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.col'))
 const winCombo = () => {
   let wonCombo = []
   winningCombos.forEach(combo => {
     if (boxes[combo[0]].innerHTML == boxes[combo[1]].innerHTML && boxes[combo[0]].innerHTML == boxes[combo[2]].innerHTML && boxes[combo[0]].innerHTML != "")
       wonCombo = combo
   })
   return wonCombo
 }
```

This returns the winning combo. You can now work with the divs at wonCombo position ans apply the css you want on them.